# Postgres regular expression in where clause

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

Is there a solution in postgres for matching as per below example:

'test' table entries:

```
id |                            url                             
----+-------------------------------------------------------------
 1  | /services/system
 2  | /services/system/{uuid}/group
 3  | /services/system/{uuid}/group/{uuid}/port
```

I want to match the following input strings against the url column that exist in table:

```
1. /services/system/1/group          --> should match row 3
2. /services/system/1/group/2/port   --> should match row 3
3. /services/system/1/group          --> should match row 2
4. /services/system/1/group/2        --> should not match
5. /services/system/1                --> should not match
```

I tried following query to match the match the 3rd row, but it did not work:

```
select * from test where regexp_replace(url, '{uuid}', '*', 'g') ~ '/services/system/1/group/1/port'
```

Any solution?

Comment: `*` isn't the wildcard character in a regex. You need to use `.+` or maybe `[0-9]+` to only match numbers

Comment: okay but '.+' didn't work either. Also the uuid placeholder may not necessarily be number.  /1/ and /2/ are just used to simplify the example.

Comment: I think you should try like this.. `select * from test where regexp_replace('/services/system/1/group/1/port', '[0-9]+', '{uuid}', 'g') = url`

Comment: @AkhileshMishra As I said, {uuid} is not a number. Also the input string is dynamic in nature, so this kind of matching isn't a generic solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering your scenarios given in question and comments you can use below query:

```sql
select * from test 
where '/services/system/1/group' ~ concat('^',replace(url,'{uuid}','[^/]+'),'$')
```

Here it will check for any character except `/` in place of `{uuid}`

**Edit**
If you want only alphanumeric then you should use try this:

```sql
select * from test 
where '/services/system/1/group' ~ concat('^',replace(url,'{uuid}','[\w]+'),'$')
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ebeb270bb3d52f6c9b51fb03564c1de2)

Comment: This query works! Thanks for the solution.

Comment: This query matches only when {uuid} is single digit. For e.g: it does not match id=3 for the following query in your demo example: select * from test where '/services/system/1001/group/2001/port' ~concat('^',replace(url,'{uuid}','[^/]'),'$')

Comment: shouldn't replacing '{uuid}' with '[\w+]' had worked? my {uuid} is alphanumeric.

Comment: downvoting as this is not a generic solution.

Comment: actually I missed `+` in it. it should be `[^/]+` . If you want to restrict to alphanumeric then you can use `[\w]+`. But if it is a statdard `uuid` then it should be '[\w-]+`. I have updated the answer